# Need to apply common settings to multiple projects in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to apply some common settings in multiple projects in Gitlab.

Could someone help me how can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup